# "Buoyed by" here means?

Tags: articles

[image]

Does it mean that the market is up or stays steady in a high level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think of a buoy on the ocean you will get the right idea.

In this context, the market held at a certain level/range (like a buoy floating on the water goes up and down) and did not drop significantly (since a buoy won't sink).